# Capistrano Net::SSH::Authentification::AgentError

Tags: deployment, capistrano

I'm trying to set up capistrano for pushing my project, using git as VCS.

I'm running capistrano on a win7 machine, and want to push on my ubuntu 64bit EC2, here is what capistrano says: http://pastebin.com/FRyzYFbE

My local SSH Client is Putty, and works pretty fine, for my deploy.rb i've set something like: http://pastebin.com/UubfdDYm

Does anyone know what's going on there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have Win7, but I can tell you what worked for me on winXP. I added an SSH config file to `%USER_HOME%/.ssh/config`

The contents of that file look like this:

```
Host dev
  User ubuntu
  Hostname example.com
  IdentityFile path/relative/to/user_home_ssh/mykey.ppk
```

The `Host` line can be the actual host or a nickname that you will use. Here, I used a short nickname. This should match the IP or hostname you use in your capistrano config.

The `User` should be the user you set in your capistrano config (ubunto in your case).

The `Hostname` is the real hostname or IP of the server you will access. The `IdentityFile` is a path relative to your `USER_HOME/.ssh` directory.

Comment: Hey, thanks at first, but still getting the same error, when i try to connect to "dev" in your case, i'm getting the same unkown response. and when i try to ssh user@dev i get "no address associated with name"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out that, because i have Git installed, the home directory for my ssh config is `C:\Program Files\Git\.ssh`

I had to fi several things there, and when it first works to connect via ssh in the command line (thanks to Git i have an SSH client installed), the connection was successfull.

There is still a bug, cause Capistrano can't do a local git command due to SSH key error, if i do the same command in the CLI, it works perfeclty. But I think I will stop using capistrano and use something easier, a remot `git pull && /build.sh` should do the trick.